# Should denial of access take place in the router, or in controller methods?

Tags: php, rest, authentication, model-view-controller, routes

I'm creating a RESTful API in PHP on an MVC framework, but I"m confused as to where the authentication check should go. On one hand, I could put it in the routing function, and authenticate based on route, or I could authenticate in the individual controller methods.

Where is the appropriate place to do this?

Comment: in the controller.

Comment: router is for routing. the controller is the semantically correct place to do auth.